# Safety of using Reviewed By field in process template

Tags: azure-devops

I have a product manager that noticed the 'Reviewed By' field as available in queries and is now asking for this to be surfaced on the process template.  According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/guidance-code-review-feedback-field-reference?view=azure-devops), this OOTB field is used in TFVC code review flows on specific work item types (Code Review Request/Response & Feedback Request/Response). My question is two parts:

- Are there risks (from a product support perspective) to adding an OOTB field meant for one purpose to additional work items for a new (though similar) purpose?
- Would I be better off creating a new custom field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there risks (from a product support perspective) to adding an OOTB
>   field meant for one purpose to additional work items for a new (though
>   similar) purpose?

Since you haven't mentioned which project type you are using, here I will talk with TFVC/Git these two different type.

As what you concerned is **from a product support perspective**, if your project is using Git type, this `Reviewed by` field added would easy to confused to figure out what metrics you and your team developer need focus one.

In fact, the `Reviewed by` is all needed during develop. Just for Git type project, this metric has integrated into the [branch policy](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/repos/git/branch-policies.md#configure-branch-policies). During develop, the developer and project leaders/admins can only need to focus on the required/optional requirements in Pull Request. As the most developers be used to is PR, the `Reviewed by` filed in WIT would easily be ignored, and also, it would make the report be more uncleared since this metric is **repeated** with the `Reviewed by option` in PR.

---

But, if what you are using is TFVC, as you know, there hasn't PR for TFVC project. At this time, the code review is a necessary method to increase overall code quality and reduce the risk of creating more bugs. The field `Reviewed by` can let this review more **traceable**.

You can add this field into the process which used by the project that relevant team is working. Then set this field as required so ensure the code review can be executed strictly.

> Would I be better off creating a new custom field?

In fact, we recommend you use the OOTB filed instead of customize new one.